# I cant generate the APK

Tags: java, android

I have a problem with my code

I finished my project and i want to generate the APK but i don't find Signed APK in the menu

I find just these items:
Please help me

You can find that in this image:

[See the Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9adEV.png)

Manifest:

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="bb.hoppingpanda"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9"/>

    <supports-screens
        android:xlargeScreens="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:anyDensity="false" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        
        <activity
            android:name="bb.hoppingpanda.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
   android:screenOrientation="landscape"
   android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
   android:configChanges="orientation">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        
        <!-- Ads Using Google Play Services SDK -->
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
               android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
        
        <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
             android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
    </application>
    
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RESTART_PACKAGES"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />

</manifest>
```

Build.gradle :

```js
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"


    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 8
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile files('libs/google-play-services.jar')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:10.0.1'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this out: https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html

You will need to add **signingConfigs** section to your gradle build.

```
  signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file("keystore.jks")
            storePassword ""
            keyAlias ""
            keyPassword ""
        }
    }
```

Then make sure you have your keystore setup properly as well. Then in your buildTypes for you release you can sign it by setting the signingConfig to the release one from above.

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            debuggable false
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
```

Comment: What about this problem :

Comment: Error:Cannot locate factory for objects of type DefaultGradleConnector, as ConnectorServiceRegistry has been closed.

Comment: Check this out - https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=80591